# Android locationClient returning null, location updates non-responsive

Tags: android, gps, locationlistener

This is my onConnected() method that is being called after I connect the locationClient. This method is called ok, so the GPS is connecting fine. However, getLastLocation() is returning null, which perhaps can be expected due to trying to get a location too soon, and the locationListener method is not being called at all. 
It's being run on a Samsung Galaxy S3. When I open the google maps app, it gets a fix on my position instantly, so the GPS must be fine.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) 
{

    Toast.makeText(context, "GPS connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    connector = new Connector();
    connector.execute("clues", null, null);
    listener = new LocationListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
        {
            Log.d("location", "listener activated");
            try
            {
            coords = locationCoords(location);
            if(coords[0] != 0)
            {
                meMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]))
                .title("Me")
                .snippet("Your position")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));   
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]), (float) 19));
            }
            Toast.makeText(context, coords[0] + ", " + coords[1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            catch(NullPointerException e)
            {
                Log.d("nulls", "null");
            }

        }
    };
    mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, listener);
    try
    {
    coords = locationCoords(new Location(mLocationClient.getLastLocation()));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]), (float) 19));
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context,"location null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    //Toast.makeText(context, coords[0] + ", " + coords[1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("location", "location updates initiated");
}
```

Defining request parameters:

```
public dbConnector(Context con, Activity acti, GoogleMap map)
{
    context = con;
    activity = acti;
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    setGPSUpdates(10000, 5000);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(updateRate);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(fastestUpdate);
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(1);
    Log.d("location", "location request constructed");
    this.map = map;


}

public void setGPSUpdates(int update, int fastupdate)
{
    updateRate = update;
    fastestUpdate = fastupdate;
}
```

Comment: set a priority and a fastest interval before you request location updates. I dont see where you do that

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps app uses both the GPS and network positioning.

Using the GPS, it is normal that the first fix gets some time to arrive. Also, it works well outside, and quite badly inside. (Also, make sure GPS is enabled)

This code works for me:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    private LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            // GPS is disabled
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
                0, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // do something with the fix
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Waited 10 minutes, no fix. Went outside, no fix. Opened google maps, instant fix. It's not the GPS itself that's the problem, something must be wrong...

Comment: I'm using the google APIs for it. It was actually working 5 days ago, then one day it just decided to stop working. I might try switching to the more traditional location services system.

Comment: @fonduman well what did you change in those 5 days? if you didnt change anything then there is probably not anything wrong with your code. Did you try restarting the device?

Comment: I defined the map marker and put it into the listener just before the GPS stopped working. Restarted the device, no change.